# char * array manipulation on recursive function

Tags: c, arrays, string, algorithm, recursion

I have a program that calculates the edit distance of two strings. it also outputs all the edit operations to obtain the complete transformation.
i wrote a recursive function that explores the matrix filled by the edit distance calculation function and reconstructs the path

## void reconstruct_path(char *s1, char *s2 ,int i, int j , matrix_t matrix)

```
 void reconstruct_path(char *s1, char *s2 int i, int j , matrix_t matrix)
 {
    if(matrix[i][j].parent == -1) return;


    if (matrix[i][j].parent == MATCH) 
    {
    reconstruct_path(s1,s2,i-1,j-1,matrix);
    match_out(s1, s2 , i, j);
    return;
    }

    if (matrix[i][j].parent == INSERT) 
    {
    reconstruct_path(s1,s2,i,j-1,matrix);
    insert_out(s2, j);
    return;
    }

    if (matrix[i][j].parent == DELETE) 
    {
    reconstruct_path(s1,s2,edit,i-1,j,matrix);
    delete_out(s1, i);
    return;
    }

}`
```

as you can notice there are three functions that this function calls

```
- void match_out(char *s1, char *s2,int i, int j)
- void insert_out(char *t, int j)
- void delete_out(char *s, int i)
```

## void match_out(char *s1, char *s2,int i, int j)

```
void match_out(char *s1, char *s2 ,int i, int j)
{
    if (s1[i] == s2[j]) 
    {
        printf("M no edit needed \n" );
    }
    else 
    {
        printf("S subst %c with %c \n",s1[i] , s2[j]);
    }
}
```

## void insert_out(char *t, int j)

```
void insert_out(char *t, int j)
{
    printf("I Insert %c\n",t[j]);
}
```

## void delete_out(char *s, int i)

```
void delete_out(char *s, int i)
{
    printf("D delete %c\n",s[i]);
}
```

this produces an output like this

> from "parent" to "cousin" :
>
> S subst p with c 
> S subst a with o 
> S subst r with u 
> S subst e with s 
> S subst n with i 
> S subst t with n

i want to improve this to obtain a more precise output like this:

> from "parent" to "cousin" :
>
> S subst p with c   parent -> carent 
> S subst a with o   carent -> corent 
> S subst r with u   corent -> couent 
> S subst e with s   couent -> cousnt 
> S subst n with i   cousnt -> cousit 
> S subst t with n   cousit -> cousin

Do you ave any suggestion? (i'm noto so good with C string manipulation)

---

[update from comments to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25972594/694576):]

What is the data type of two strings which are recieved in `s1` and `s2`? (asked by [*vj1207*](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2229448/vj1207))

They are declared in `main()` like this `char *str_a = " parent"; char *str_b = " cousin";`

Comment: Your code does not compile. You declare `match_out` with 5 input arguments, but use it with 4. You declare `reconstruct_path` with 5 input arguments, but use it with 6.

Comment: you're right. It was a copy paste error :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add few line in **match_out**

```
void match_out(char *s1, char *s2, char **edit ,int i, int j)
{
    if (s1[i] == s2[j]) 
    {
        printf("M no edit needed \n" );
    }
    else 
    {
        printf("S subst %c with %c ",s1[i] , s2[j]);
        //**from here**
        printf("%s -> ",s1);
        s1[i]=s2[j];
        printf("%s\n",s1);
        //upto here
    }
}
```

---

Update

you can declare the char array  as

```
char str[]= {'p','a','r','e','n','t'};
```

if you declare it as

```
char * str = "parent";
```

then you can't modify it. And that is why you were getting the mentioned error.

Comment: check that `j` and `i` are not negative. also why do you pass matrix by value? you don't seem to modify it. is it a 2D array?

Comment: 1)There are no negative values. there is only one -1 that is strategically placed on matrix[0][0] as placeholder for the root element.2)yes it is a 2D array 3) It's not by value matrix_t is defined as `typedef  struct m_bucket **  matrix_t;`

Comment: what is the data type of two strings which are recieved in s1 and s2 ?

Comment: They are declared in main() like this `char *str_a = " parent"; char *str_b = " cousin";`.

Comment: Then that is the problem. when you declare it as char *str_a = " parent"; then you can't modify it because it will be literal. You can not modify literal. I am updating the correct way of declaration in  my answer.

Comment: Thanks! @vj1207 you're right. this partially solves my problem but it is a good starting point. Do you know how to pass from `*str_a to str_a[]` ?